# CodeIgniter not loading the core

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

This is outrages, I have been trying to configure CodeIgniter V3.1.3 for 3 hours now.

Everything was working perfectly I uploaded it on the web, changed the `base_url` and it doesn't won't to work:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function base_url()

Filename: /var/www/html/sub/application/views/errors/html/error_404.php

Line Number: 184

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/sub/index.php
Line: 316
Function: require_once
```

Line 316 is where it loads core files

When i print the:

`BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php'` -->
`/var/www/html/sub/system/core/CodeIgniter.php`

The path is ok

Here my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

### Tried

- I tried switching to all types of uri_protocol.
- Multiple stack answers revolve around htaccess

### Server

- Debian Jessie
- PHP 7
- Apache 2.4

### Help

So everything works normally on Local, I re uploaded all the files 2-3 times.
**At this point I thinks its something to do with the server**

## Update

PHP Variables:
[image: Php vars]

Comment: check to make sure the file which contains the base_url function got transferred to the server properly and indeed has the right permissions and ownership on it. I am not sure which file the base_url() function is in, sorry.

Comment: Have you followed the class and file name method of codeigniter way case sensitive https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @wolfgang1983 You YOU!!!!! I owe you a beer... So the default controller I made after hand had the small letter and all other styled Ucfirst. Please post an answer

Comment: @Maverick added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your filenames and class names have **only the first letter upper case**, codeigniter case sensitive

As explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Welcome.php and

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {}
```

Comment: Unfortunately git is by default not case sensitive and when i corrected this it didn't commit so this is why I didn't saw it at first. Really strange who it worked on localhost ?

Comment: It worked on local as the change was made, if you deployed to an external server using git then it didnt have the local changes.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `application/config/autoload.php` and **add URL Helper**

Line 92 (assume)

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

---

And `.htaccess` should be

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ohhhhh I forgot to tell you that of course I added it, as I said it worked in Local :(

Comment: BTW you probably ment `application/config/autoload.php` not config right?

Comment: make sure all the folder are updated as well chnages i have did

Answer (score 0):

You must call `$this->load->helper('url');` to use `base_url()` method. Although you must use `CI_Controller` class to on your controller class.